# Integrating MoPub with Admob Mediation. Bug build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, ads, onesignal, mopub

I want to integrate MoPub using Admob mediation according to the instructions:
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation/mopub

I have problems on - Step 3: Import the MoPub SDK and adapter

After adding the Maven repository to the application level build.gradle file:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds" }
}
```

I get errors:

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@productionDebug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.0, 16.0.0).
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@productionDebug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@productionDebug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@productionDebug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@productionDebugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.0, 16.0.0).
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@productionDebugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@productionDebugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@productionDebugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@productionDebugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:[10.2.1, 12.1.0).
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@productionDebugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[10.2.1, 12.1.0).
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@productionRelease/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.0, 16.0.0).
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@productionRelease/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@productionRelease/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@productionRelease/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@productionReleaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:[10.2.1, 12.1.0).
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@productionReleaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[10.2.1, 12.1.0).
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

My build.gradle files:

- Module: app level
  https://gist.github.com/TheKrushik/0f5dcb2714fd48c3c19786e6229a9ceb
- Project level
  https://gist.github.com/TheKrushik/7a5d6fbb017d23770212b65afac07d58

I noticed that if you disable the OneSignal SDK, the project compiles without problems

```
    // OneSignal
//    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.11.1'
```

But I need this library.
I understand that I have a problem at the repository level, but how can I solve it?

Comment: Will you got any solution?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If your project is running AndroidX, you will need to make sure you migrate since our SDK isn't yet.

1) With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, you can quickly migrate an existing project to use AndroidX by selecting Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX from the menu bar.

2) In your gradle.properties file, set the following two flags to true:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: I am using AndroidX. In the gradle.properties file, these options are set.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solve this nightmare :

```
 implementation('com.mopub:mopub-sdk:5.11.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
 }

 implementation('com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.13.0'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-location'
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
    exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-iid'
 }
```